# How to get current location name from longitude and latitude?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm using this code to get the current location of the user through google maps api and i am getting the location in the form of latitude and longitudes and getting the location in LatLng variable.

But after that when I am converting the latitude and longitude to an address then its not working.

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p){
var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude,p.coords.longitude);
    alert(LatLng);
    alert(p.coords.latitude);
    alert(p.coords.longitude);
    var mapOptions = {
         center: LatLng,
         zoom: 13,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'LatLng': LatLng }, function (results, status){
        alert(geocoder);   
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
             if (results[1]){
                 alert("Location: " + results[1].formatted_address);
             }
        }
});
```

Comment: **javascript != java**

Comment: Remove the tag java, Java and javascript are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var currgeocoder;

     //Set geo location  of lat and long

     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position, html5Error) {

         geo_loc = processGeolocationResult(position);
         currLatLong = geo_loc.split(",");
         initializeCurrent(currLatLong[0], currLatLong[1]);

    });

    //Get geo location result

   function processGeolocationResult(position) {
         html5Lat = position.coords.latitude; //Get latitude
         html5Lon = position.coords.longitude; //Get longitude
         html5TimeStamp = position.timestamp; //Get timestamp
         html5Accuracy = position.coords.accuracy; //Get accuracy in meters
         return (html5Lat).toFixed(8) + ", " + (html5Lon).toFixed(8);
   }

    //Check value is present or not & call google api function

    function initializeCurrent(latcurr, longcurr) {
         currgeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         console.log(latcurr + "-- ######## --" + longcurr);

         if (latcurr != '' && longcurr != '') {
             var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latcurr, longcurr);
             return getCurrentAddress(myLatlng);
         }
   }

    //Get current address

     function getCurrentAddress(location) {
          currgeocoder.geocode({
              'location': location

        }, function(results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log(results[0]);
                $("#address").html(results[0].formatted_address);
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
     }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly as the commentator Parker told, jsp and java tags are irrelevant for your post. I removed it.

You should do the reverse geocoding. *The process of doing the converse, translating a location on the map into a human-readable address, is known as reverse geocoding.*

Please refer the below google map url for [**Reverse Geocoding**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse).

See the below snippet of mapping lat & lan to location,

```
 var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
 geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      if (results[0]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: latlng,
         map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
```

Let me know if it helps.